# Alguien sabe como hacer una matriz en python, pero que tenga de valores un objeto de una clase

Tags: python, numpy, matriz

Tengo este codigo, y quiero que la matriz de matches, tenga como valor un objeto Match(), seria bueno que me ayuden porfa comunidad, derrepente tengo que usar otro modulo uu

```
import numpy as np

class Match:
    local = -1
    visitor = -1

teams_number = 4

rounds_number = teams_number - 1
matches_per_round = int(teams_number/2)

matches = np.empty((rounds_number, matches_per_round))

for i in range(rounds_number):

    k=0

    for j in range(matches_per_round):

        matches[i,j] = Match()
        k+=1

        if k == rounds_number: 
            k = 0


for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

Comment: Y cual es el problema que tienes? Hay algún error o que cosa no funciona con tu código?

Comment: "Me sale este error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\PC MASTER RACE\Downloads\Borrar\Snake-Test\asd.py", line 20, in <module>
    matches[i,j] = Match()
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'Match'"

Comment: Ahora te doy una respuesta, hay algunas correcciones que no puedo hacer en los comentarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema ocurre por que `numpy` espera que coloques un `float` como tipo de dato. Si deseas colocar otro tipo de objeto debes de especificarlo al momento de crear el array. Esta sería la solución:

```py
matches = np.empty((rounds_number, matches_per_round), dtype=Match)
#el parametro dtype indica el tipo de dato del arreglo
```

Ahora tu problema estaría solucionado, excepto que al momento de imprimir tu array obtendrás algo *"raro"*. En vez de ver números verás la dirección de memoria del objeto creado. Algo así:

```py
[<__main__.Match object at 0x7efc3da65c50> <__main__.Match object at 0x7efc3da65050>]
[<__main__.Match object at 0x7efc3da65590> <__main__.Match object at 0x7efc3da650d0>]
[<__main__.Match object at 0x7efc3da65650> <__main__.Match object at 0x7efc3da655d0>]
```

Para evitar esto deberías implementar el método `__repr__` en tu clase `Match`, lo que hace este método es definir como es que se imprimirá tu clase al momento de usar `print` o en cualquier otro momento que se requiera de su representación. Para poder mostrar los valores que has definido al momento de crear la clase, lo mejor es que estos valores sean valores de instancia y no de clase, no profundizaré demasiado en eso, si quieres puedes buscar sobre atributos de clase y atributos de instancia.

Tu código de la clase `Match` quedaría así:

```py
class Match:
    def __init__(self):
        self.local = -1
        self.visitor = -1
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'local:{self.local}\tvisitor:{self.visitor}'
        # puedes retornar cualquier string (debe ser string obligatoriamente)
```

Con esto ya obtenemos algo más amigable:

```
[local:-1   visitor:-1 local:-1 visitor:-1]
[local:-1   visitor:-1 local:-1 visitor:-1]
[local:-1   visitor:-1 local:-1 visitor:-1]
```